# Bad value for attribute autofocus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, autofocus, angular-template

We are using [`grunt-html-angular-validate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-angular-validate) package for HTML lints. It uses W3C [online validator tool](http://validator.w3.org/) under-the-hood and, so far, it did a great job in validating our angular templates.

Today, it failed while checking the latest changes pulled from the repository with the following error:

> Validating src/login/login.html ...ERROR [L37:C108]
>
> Bad value
>   {{regCodeRequired}} for attribute autofocus on element input.

Here are the related lines where it fails:

```
<div class="auth-reg-code-block" ng-if="regCodeRequired">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="regCode" 
           id="regCode" ng-model="user.regCode" autofocus="{{regCodeRequired}}" 
           placeholder="Registration Code" required>
</div>
```

This is basically a field for entering a registration code for the two-factor authentication. `regCodeRequired` is a boolean variable that is set to `true` once the user passed the first login/password authentication step.

And I see the input appearing with a focus on it (using chrome 39) - it is working.

**Question:**

I'm pretty sure there is a reason for the validation tool to complain, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Are we using `autofocus` attribute incorrectly? How should we fix the validation error?

I've looked through the [W3C validator errors](http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html) trying to find an explanation, but there is nothing about `autofocus` there. Also, nothing inside the [`w3cjs` github repository](https://github.com/thomasdavis/w3cjs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autofocus).

---

Here is the grunt configuration for `htmlangular`:

```
htmlangular: {
    options: {
        relaxerror: [
            'Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.',
            'Attribute href without an explicit value seen.',
            '& did not start a character reference.',
            'not allowed on element form at this point.',
            'not allowed as child of element',
            'Element img is missing required attribute src.'
        ],
        reportpath: null
    },
    all: [
        "<%= app.src %>/*.html",
        "<%= app.src %>/**/*.html"
    ]
}
```

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Couple of sanity checks for you: you have only **one** `autofocus` attribute specified in your document at one time; you are setting the attribute value to "" (empty string) or "autofocus" (to represent `true`), or are not setting the value at all (e.g. `<input ... autofocus>`) (any other values are invalid). Perhaps the validator is confused with the angular syntax because it isn't expecting an explicit value?

Comment: i might be wrong, but have you tried ```ng-autofocus```

Comment: @Cory thanks for the inputs. `autofocus` is set only on this input and the value is getting set to `true/false` - at least, this is not right. But, this is static analysis, it cannot know what the value of the scope variable would be - I suspect it doesn't like the angular syntax there..

Comment: @Cory if you would elaborate more on how to proceed to fix the error, it can be a legitimate answer here. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like  grunt-html-angular-validate module is running the validation before the angular digest cycle gets applies to the template, that's why it is trying to validate the unprocessed statement `{{regCodeRequired}}` instead of the processed value true or false. Can you provide the code for your initConfig? Did you check if `options.angular` is set to true in your initConfig?

Comment: @JoseMendez edited the question with the `htmlangular` grunt task configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that when autofocus is present in a webpage the element will have the focus. `autofocus` is boolean meaning that it just has to be present to activate the focus. If you use `autofocus="false"` the element will still have the focus. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kec7qv8/ The correct usage example of autofocus is: <input type="text" autofocus />

Comment: The `input` is only displayed if `regCodeRequired` true, so a value for `autofocus` would be unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the specs, the `autofocus` attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
>   To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
>   altogether.

The last paragraph pretty much explains why the validator is complaining.

In other words, you can replace

```
<div class="auth-reg-code-block" ng-if="regCodeRequired">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="regCode" 
           id="regCode" ng-model="user.regCode" autofocus="{{regCodeRequired}}" 
           placeholder="Registration Code" required>
</div>
```

with:

```
<div class="auth-reg-code-block" ng-if="regCodeRequired">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="regCode" 
           id="regCode" ng-model="user.regCode" autofocus
           placeholder="Registration Code" required>
</div>
```

---

You might be interested in [ng-autofocus plugin](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-autofocus).

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I'm wrong: since this `regCodeRequired` binding would be evaluated to true/false - we are using `autofocus` correctly. Would you recommend making the validator ignore the error in this case?

Comment: `autofocus` is a boolean attribute, just like `required`. Both `autofocus="true"` and `autofocus="false"` are incorrect; both will be interpreted as `autofocus` attribute *is present* causing the input to autofocus. Since the input is shown when regCodeRequired is true, you can safely replace `autofocus="{{regCodeRequired}}"` with `autofocus`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the angular option explicitly to true in your configuration (this should enables the process (digest) of the angular bindings {{}} and {{regCodeRequired}} should be substituted for the value of the variable  regCodeRequired before it validate the html):

```
htmlangular: {
    options: {
        angular: true, //per documentation: Turns on ignoring of validation errors that are caused by AngularJS.
        relaxerror: [
            'Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.',
            'Attribute href without an explicit value seen.',
            '& did not start a character reference.',
            'not allowed on element form at this point.',
            'not allowed as child of element',
            'Element img is missing required attribute src.'
        ],
        reportpath: null
    },
    all: [
        "<%= app.src %>/*.html",
        "<%= app.src %>/**/*.html"
    ]
}
```

If this doesn't works then you'll need to treat this parameter as a custom directive:

```
 options: {
        customattrs: ['autofocus']
     //...
 }
```

Per documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-angular-validate

options.customattrs

Type: Array Default value: []

List all of the custom attributes you have created through directives and other means here. The validator will ignore warnings about these attributes.

You can use the * wildcard, e.g.: 'custom-attrs-*'

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help! Neither option worked for me - same error. Though, I would like to see not only how to suppress the error , but also an insight about `autofocus` in general - as I understand we are not working with it correctly. FYI, adding `'for attribute autofocus on element input'` to the `relaxerror` helps to ignore the error.